how can I resize a window when I absolutely cannot get to the bottom of the window?
This is a silly problem, but very annoying. The app in question is the Minecraft launcher. The problem is that it has been re-sized to the point where the bottom-right corner of the window is not reachable. It is below my monitor display. And there is no "Maximize" button in this window. There is only "Minimize" (which, despite its name, does not resize the window) and Close.
I have tried changing the resolution of the monitor. Once upon a time with another app, this worked. I set the resolution to very low, the window was re-sized to fit. Then, making the resolution higher left the window with the same number of pixels and therefore smaller. But this trick is not working here. The minecraft launcher may be too "smart". :--(
Is there a secret gnome-* command that will resize something?

Don't rely on the mouse, instead rely on window-related keyboard shortcuts. I believe, the default combination is either the bucky key (the "windows" key) operated together with one of the arrow keys, or the Alt key and one of the arrows. (E.g. left and right arrow will resize the window and place it to the left or right side of the screen correspondingly. The up-arrow will resize to fill (and fit) the entire screen.) The default window-related modifier key (windows vs Alt keys) should be configurable somewhere.

Also, what version of Ubuntu and what version of Gnome / Gnome-shell?

Apologies.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

It looks as though it may be ML doing this. The window cannot resize smaller than some of the content inside and that content is really tall. They could do a vertically scrollable window, but apparently they are not. Amazingly lame.
